# 403 Forbidden wordpress in subdirectory with codeigniter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am having a rather annoying issue with running a wordpress blog site from a within subdirectory of a codeigniter application.

The main codeigniter site works fine as it always has, and I have now tried to add a wordpress blog that sits in a subdirectory in the root of this in a folder called 'blog' but when I try to get to the URL:

```
`http://sociavise.co.uk/blog`
```

A 403 forbidden is shown - but then refreshing the page allows the page to be viewed..I'm not quite sure what's going on and iv'e tried many different configurations found within the pages of this site to no avail!

The .htaccess for the main codeigniter site is as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^203\.0\.113\.0
RewriteRule (.*) "http\:\/\/example\.co.uk\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.co.uk\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|blog)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^libwww-perl*" block_bad_bots
Deny from env=block_bad_bots
```

And the wordpress .htaccess is as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Im hoping somone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance, Jamie.

Comment: tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log what does it say?

Comment: Hi Sandro, for this website the error says: `[Wed Oct 09 16:40:20 2013] [error] [client 109.204.9.98] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/www.sociavise.co.uk/blog/, referer: http://sociavise.co.uk/` 

`[Wed Oct 09 16:44:58 2013] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE`

Comment: Are those the entire wordpress and CI `.htaccess`? The `DEFLATE` error indicates there is a directive in an `.htaccess` somewhere that calls `DEFLATE` which isn't installed. This might be messing with the server reading `blog/index.php` and throwing the Directory index error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
```

Open httpd.conf and remove # before the line LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
Restart the apache.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Enabling the deflate_module got rid of the error message, however I still had the same issue - strange thing is - it only affects that specific folder/url. I ended up installing another subdirectory with a fresh wordpress install and used a different URL which seems to work for me. this saves me time messing around and gets allows me to crack on. Thanks again for your input guys.

Jamie.

Answer (score 0):

The issue suddenly occurred on the new directory.
I disabled caching and the error went away, I will try and re-enable soon and see if it comes back again. Strange!